# Angular directives causing long load times

Tags: angularjs

We currently have a large complex application build using Angular (1.3).
I have a page that is maybe using 20 custom directives (nested).
I'm finding the load time (angular bootstrap) is very slow especially on android.
Using chrome timeline profiling I can see the angular bootstrap is taking about 800ms on desktop, but about 8 seconds on android (using remote debug).
This is on a fairly new android phone (samsung s5).  However on an iPhone 5 (it takes no more than 4 seconds.

My question is does directive compilation have to take that long?  I don't think my directives link functions are actually taking long to execute.  Will replacing directives withe a combination of ng-include/ng-controller make it better?  Will replace 20 directives with one big directive make a difference?

Why would the mobile chrome browser be so less performant than iOS safari browser and very similiar hardware?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to the high number of requests a browser makes to render your website. Each directive has a template, so that's 20 requests on top of all the others (js files, images, css etc). You also have to consider that each directive/template is loaded when its parent directive/template is loaded since they are nestled, and this can make a huge impact on performance.

It may also load faster on desktop and varies on mobile based on a browsers simultaneous connection limit. I believe for iOS safari it is 6, and mobile chrome is 4.

You need to reduce the amount of template loading, and ensure you are making use of a browsers cache. In your case it may be better to combine some directives to improve performance.

Comment: Nope we put all templates in a file that is put on the page ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your fisrt question

> My question is does directive compilation have to take that long?

No. Angularjs can handle much more than 20 custom directives quickly according to my experience.

> I don't think my directives link functions are actually taking long to execute.

I think you may run into issues and need to spend time on optimization probably. Maybe too much DOM manipulating or HTML reflow.

Your second question

> Will replacing directives withe a combination of ng-include/ng-controller make it better?

I don't think so. ng-include/ng-controller are also directives. There is no essential difference.

Your third question

> Will replace 20 directives with one big directive make a difference?

No. The number of directives doesn't matter. What matter is what directive does.

And your last question. It's a fact sucks and torments me long time. I also don't know why.

Comment: I will check my directives for any HTML reflow, but I think it will be minimal. And I know there is minimal DOM manipulations.  The templates are quite large and do contain a lot of markup including nested directives.
I think this could be why it takes long to compile since the angular compile phase has to traverse though it all to pull out ALL directives to compile?
When I say 'long' I mean about 1-2 seconds for just compliation - NOT considering the 'link' phase, since I can defer the linking with ng-if.

Comment: I just can't believe the compile stage can take so long (1-2s) on Android for what I consider to be minimal amount of directives.